# OData : Operands of logical operator 'AND' are not valid

Tags: filter, odata, sap-business-bydesign

I am trying to call an OData report with the following URL :

> https://myXXXXX.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/crm_customerinvoicing_analytics.svc/RPCRMCIVIB_Q0001QueryResults?&$filter=PARA_CAL_DAY%20gt%20datetime%272017-01-01T00:00:00.000%27%20and%20PARA_CAL_DAY%20lt%20datetime%272017-01-02T00:00:00.000%27&$skip=0

As you can see I am trying to use the **and** operator inside a **filter** property but I received the error in the title of this post.

I tried :

```
$filter=(MyFilter1) and (MyFilter2)
$filter=(MyFilter1 and MyFilter2)
$filter=(MyFilter1 AND MyFilter2)
```

But I still have an error. Any ideas ?

Comment: Does it work if you just use one of the filters?

Comment: what is the spec version of the OData service? V2? V4?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this thread first, this is error occurs when the same field is used to filter the dataset twice (greater than+less than, greater than+less than or equal to, etc)
[SAP issue report](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/2600188)

Answer (score 0):

All the evidence (documentation, forums, Github page, etc.) led to believe this type of filtering doesn't work. Out of desperation I tried a suggestion from [this closed issue](https://github.com/SAP/C4CODATAAPIDEVGUIDE/issues/6) on the Github dev guide, even though the answer to that question specifically said that it wouldn't work. And, guess what? It did! If you `ge` and `le` instead of `gt` and `lt` the `and` operator in the filter works. For example, this doesn't work:

`CreationDateTime gt datetimeoffset'2023-05-20T00:00:00Z' and (CreationDateTime lt datetimeoffset'2023-05-20T01:00:00Z')`

But this works:

`CreationDateTime ge datetimeoffset'2023-05-20T00:00:00Z' and (CreationDateTime le datetimeoffset'2023-05-20T01:00:00Z')`